# Go Library - async.auto for golang

Tags: go

In Nodejs, we have async.auto (http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.auto) which automatically manages the fan out order through a topological sort.

Is there a similar library in Go that manages your order of requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

https://github.com/kamildrazkiewicz/go-flow

It's based on channels draining (async.auto uses topological sort) but it works in similar way.